# Using dataTable with dynamic nested tables from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data from an AJAX request in the format:

```
{
81920: {
  1: ['David Johnson'],
  2: ['Jarvis Landry', 'Mark Ingram']
},
38913: {
  1: ['Julio Jones', 'T.Y. Hilton', 'Jordan Howard'],
  2: ['David Johnson']
}
```

And I want to display it in a table, like (empty cells left blank):

```
Side 1        | Side 2
-----------------------------
David Johnson | Jarvis Landry
(empty cell)  | Mark Ingram
-----------------------------
Julio Jones   | David Johnson
T.Y. Hilton   | (empty cell)
Jordan Howard | (empty cell)
-----------------------------
```

I initialize the datatable with:

```
var trade_table;

trade_table = $('#trades').dataTable( {
      columns: [
          { title: "team1 gave" },
          { title: "team2 gave"}
      ],
      paging: false,
      info: false
    } );
```

And I want try to update it after my AJAX request with:

```
success: function(response) {
        // clear table and add new data
        $('#trades').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $('#trades').dataTable().fnAddData(response);

      }
```

I can change the format of the data if needed to use just a list instead of a JSON, or some other format. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get chance to check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750154/display-nested-json-data-in-jquery-datatables

Comment: That helped me a bit, thanks!  I decided to change the way I was returning data to return a string of players involved on each side, so now it's just a 2D array with no nested tables, which was simple to get working.